# QVideoWidget inside a GraphicsView

Tags: qt, video

I am trying to put a `QVideoWidget` inside a `QGraphicsView` but it doesn't work.

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
QVideoWidget videoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(&videoWidget);
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy
        = scene.addWidget(&videoWidget);
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
player->setMedia(
            QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/cedric/Vidéos/musique_21sec.mp4"));
player->play();
view.show();
```

With that I get only a black window. However, the sound is playing. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

It works with a `QraphicsVideoItem`, but I don't want to use that since I cannot change brightness with that. Outside of a `QGraphicsView` the `QVideoWidget` works well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having similar problems with rendering a QVideoWidget using a QPainter. Try the following code:


`QPalette palette; palette.setColor( QPalette::Background, Qt::blue ); videoWidget->setPalette( palette ); `

Does this make the window blue instead of black?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. I posted an issue about to the Qt team and got this answer: "This can't work, and never will. A QVideoWidget requires a native window handle for the video to be rendered onto it, and a QWidget inside a QGraphicsProxyWidget can't have a native window handle. If you need brightness/contrast adjustment, you will have to create a custom video graphics item and do the processing on the video frames yourself.". (cf https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35299)